# Costmap2DROS transform timeout.Could not get robot pose, cancelling reconfiguration

Tags: slam, navigation, costmap, hector

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi , I am doing an experiment  about hector slam navigation.

for the picture as below,the small tf mark is where it start and the big one is the last place .

here is my launch file ([click me to github](https://github.com/AlysonQ/rplidar_ros/blob/master/launch/expolration.launch))

[image: image description]

But the system crash when the laser scanner move every time about 10 seconds.

And shows Costmap2DROS transform timeout and can't get robot pose.

(update stauts 2016.02.27)

I guess this warning is because of the setting I modify.

I modify "hector_navigation/hector_exploration_node/config/costmap.yaml",change "  transform_tolerance: 2 " to "  transform_tolerance: 10".

[image: image description]
[image: image description]

How could I solve it? Thanks for anyone response.><

---

Here are the error message.

[ INFO] [126.662293041]: [hector_exploration_planner] Initializing HectorExplorationPlanner

[ INFO] [126.843700868]: [hector_exploration_planner] Parameter set. security_const: 0.500000, min_obstacle_dist:
1000, plan_in_unknown: 1, use_inflated_obstacle: 1, p_goal_angle_penalty_:50 , min_frontier_size: 5, p_dist_for_goal_reached_: 0.250000, same_frontier: 0.250000

[ WARN] [178.280680532]: Costmap2DROS transform timeout. Current time: 178.2801, global_pose stamp: 168.1918, tolerance: 10.0000

[ WARN] [178.281182366]: Could not get robot pose, cancelling reconfiguration

[ WARN] [179.391044619]: Costmap2DROS transform timeout. Current time: 179.3909, global_pose stamp: 168.1918,
tolerance: 10.0000

[ WARN] [179.391814787]: Could not get robot pose, cancelling reconfiguration

[ WARN] [180.400909692]: Costmap2DROS transform timeout. Current time: 180.4008, global_pose stamp: 168.1918, tolerance: 10.0000

[ WARN] [180.406124285]: Could not get robot pose, cancelling reconfiguration

[ WARN] [181.480204223]: Costmap2DROS transform timeout. Current time: 181.4799, global_pose stamp: 168.1918, tolerance: 10.0000

[ WARN] [181.480478224]: Could not get robot pose, cancelling reconfiguration

[ WARN] [182.480537195]: Costmap2DROS transform timeout. Current time: 182.4804, global_pose stamp: 168.1918, tolerance: 10.0000

[ WARN] [182.480666779]: Could not get robot pose, cancelling reconfiguration

[ WARN] [183.580379513]: Costmap2DROS transform timeout. Current time: 183.5802, global_pose stamp: 168.1918, tolerance: 10.0000

[ WARN] [183.580514430]: Could not get robot pose, cancelling reconfiguration

[ WARN] [184.629115323]: Costmap2DROS transform timeout. Current time: 184.6289, global_pose stamp: 168.1918, tolerance: 10.0000

[ WARN] [184.680667166]: Could not get robot pose, cancelling reconfiguration

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227638/costmap2dros-transform-timeout.could-not-get-robot-pose,-cancelling-reconfiguration/) by [YingHua](https://answers.ros.org/users/24018/yinghua/) on ROS Answers with karma: 196 on 2016-02-26

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vaziri](https://answers.ros.org/users/26088/vaziri/) on 2016-02-26**:
Your tolerance for transforms is set to 10.000 meaning that the system will not use transform information that is more than 10 seconds old.Your system is not getting any new TF messages after 168.19 . Read about tf and do the tutorials - http://wiki.ros.org/tf, then update with more info

**Comment by [YingHua](https://answers.ros.org/users/24018/yinghua/) on 2016-02-26**:
I make some test yesterday. I guess that SLAM system crash is not because of this warning.
Maybe the system sway too much make it crash.But if I want to resolve this warning,should I study more about tf ?

**Comment by [YingHua](https://answers.ros.org/users/24018/yinghua/) on 2016-02-26**:
Thanks for your response!!vaziri :) I update my question already.

**Comment by [julimen5](https://answers.ros.org/users/31894/julimen5/) on 2018-03-24**:
did you fix this? im having troubles too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a related question (duplicate?) [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/215256/costmap2dros-transform-timeout/?answer=325083#post-id-325083), will post same answer in both.

In our case it was a performance issue, the computer was not strong enough to manage the load. I changed rviz configuration to prevent pointcloud visualisation, laserscanner vis, and furthermore I was having  a process consuming 100% CPU (a node which was not sleeping while spinning). After those fixes, now everything is back to normal.

---

Originally posted by [Oscar Lima](https://answers.ros.org/users/21475/oscar-lima/) with karma: 831 on 2019-06-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1